# Heroku PHP how to install OAuth

Tags: php, heroku, oauth

How the heck do you install the PHP OAuth package on Heroku?

The Heroku docs say this https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions
which then says
The following third-party extensions can be enabled through composer.json (internal identifier names given in parentheses):

and then it refers to http://docs.php.net/oauth

I have it working locally as I installed it according to directions, but the Heroku directions are extremely lacking.

what are you suppose to put in composer.json? 
Does anyone have any experience installing the OAuth package on heroku?

Comment: Did you try `"ext-oauth": "*"` in your `composer.json`?

Comment: I didn't try that, but thats it! thanks so much. ps. how is anyone suppose to know that is what should be used? is it a standard convention?

Comment: I agree it's a bit cryptic in the docs, but it is there. I had the similar issue while ago, so that's how I knew what to try in your case :-)